# jquery on click event, a href within li tag

Tags: html, html-lists, jquery

I have a UL which I populate in the following way:

```
$("#dropdownFloorplanGroups").append("<li><a href='#'>" + value.Name + "</a></li>");
```

This displays correctly on my browser

However I can't seem to fire off the click event, which then alerts the name that I have set in the `<li></li>`

I tried this, but nothing gets fired.

```
$('li a').click(function (e) {
                alert($(this).find("a").text());                
            });
```

What should the jquery click event be?

Comment: ,You bind the event on "a that is a descendant of li". So `this` will refer to that element, the link itself. You can't use `find` on it to look for a contained link in it, necause it is the link itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use event delegation:

```
$('#dropdownFloorplanGroups').on('click', 'li a', function(e) {
    alert($(this).text());                
});
```

`$('li a')` won't take into account the newly created elements.

Comment: Your original code applies the click event only to the elements which existed at that point when the code was executed, while the code given here binds to the document element (always available) and check whether any element clicked in the document follows the pattern described in the second parameter and if it does, triggers this function.

Comment: @Aeolun: Binding to the `document` is what `.live()` did. This one is bound to `#dropdownFloorplanGroups`, which is faster.

Comment: @Blender: I stand corrected. I missed it completely, and you are right.